# Laravel 4 RESTful API data return types

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4

When createing a RESTful API with Laravel 4 and the repositories pattern (MVRC) is it best to declare a function such as

```
returnData($data, $dataType = 'JSON' ) {

    if( $dataType == 'XML' ) {

        return SimpleXML($data);
    }
    else {

        return json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

within the BaseController or is it best practice to place this in a helper library class? or maybe somewhere else?

Comment: Is XML responses really necessary? It will only bring overhead to your API supporting multiple response types and will cause some headaches along the way. I would suggesting sticking to JSON, unless XML is something you **must** have for your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in fact I did something similar in the BaseController in the project I'm working on:

```
public function smart_response($data, $redirect_to_route = null, $route_params = array())
{       
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        return Response::json($data);
    }
    else
    {
        Alert::boolean($data['msg'], $data['success']);
        return is_null($redirect_to_route) ? Redirect::back() : Redirect::to_route($redirect_to_route, $route_params);
    }
}
```

I guess you can get my idea.

Maybe you could use a post filter too? But I don't think there is a right or wrong solution for this.